# Using a pipe in powershell -Command argument

Tags: command-line, ssh, powershell, vmware

I have a Windows machine with openssh-server running and I can execute commands through it.  For example...

**This works:**

```
ssh vc-mgmt powershell -nologo -Command "get-vm"
```

**This does not work:**

```
ssh vc-mgmt powershell -nologo -Command "get-vm | get-snapshot"
```

Returns error:

> 'get-snapshot' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

If I open Powershell manually and run `get-vm | get-snapshot` it works as expected.

**My Question:**  How can I get the 2nd example to work?

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out the | was being interpreted by ssh.  I just needed to add single quotes to the command SSH will execute.  The following works.

```
ssh vc-mgmt 'powershell -nologo -Command "get-vm | get-snapshot"'
```